# Why react router switch doesn't work when window location changed?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

React router switch works fine when I using Redirects, Navlinks or other library staff.

The problem is in function **loadOrderPage**. When its fired,  window location changes OK but page not re-render accordingly to react-router switch rules, so component for '/order' doesn't render after this function complete.

here is my simple react class

Live working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-wildflower-sdvd4?file=/src/App.js

```html
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Redirect,
  Route,
  Switch,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Startpage from "./components/startpage";
import Orderpage from "./components/orderpage";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class App extends React.Component {

.......

  loadOrderPage = () => {
    this.props.history.push("/order");
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/order">
            <Orderpage />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Startpage/>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Whats wrong? I want to able change window location in functions and waiting that react router would render correct components under switch rules. May be its more suitable methods are available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have two  defined, both in your `index.js` and in your `App.js`. Remove the `<Router></Router>` from your `App.js`.

Make sure to add `exact` to your `<Route />`.

```
<Route exact path="/order">
  <Orderpage />
</Route>
<Route exact path="/">
   <Startpage/>
</Route>
```

Comment: Are you sure `<Orderpage />` works correctly? Are you able to render simple text instead of it?

Comment: yes im sure and simple <Redirect to=''/order'> works fine

Comment: even if I refresh my page after history push its renders OK

Comment: added live code example here, https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-wildflower-sdvd4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Okay, I see what is wrong. Let me update my answer.

Comment: A working example based on your codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-glitter-w43p1